# Windows XP repaints OpenGL application without any messages

Tags: windows, opengl, paint

I'm using Windows XP with a pretty old Intel video adapter (82945G). It supports OpenGL 1.1.

There is a simple OpenGL application. It processes WM_PAINT message and draws the scene.

The problem is that when I press the Start button the window gets completely erased. Some rubbish appears there. The same situation is happening when I hover cursor on close button and a tooltip appears.

I have checked that the application receives no messages during that. 
Something makes me think that windows just repaints desktop and erases my window. How could I avoid that?

Run the application. Make sure that window is on the desktop. Resize it a bit. the press start button or hover cursor over close button and waint until tooltip appear.

Here is a source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>

HDC hDC=NULL;
HGLRC hRC=NULL;
HWND hWnd=NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

bool keys[256];
bool active=TRUE;
bool fullscreen=TRUE;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    if (height==0)height=1;

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int InitGL(GLvoid)
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    return TRUE;
}

int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)
{
    GLuint PixelFormat;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    DWORD dwExStyle;
    DWORD dwStyle;
    RECT WindowRect;
    WindowRect.left=(long)0;
    WindowRect.right=(long)width;
    WindowRect.top=(long)0;
    WindowRect.bottom=(long)height;
    fullscreen=fullscreenflag;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL";

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed To Register The Window Class.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;
    }

    dwExStyle=WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    dwStyle=WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);

    // Create The Window
    if (!(hWnd=CreateWindowEx( dwExStyle,"OpenGL", title,dwStyle |
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |WS_CLIPCHILDREN,0, 0,WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,
        WindowRect.bottom-
        WindowRect.top,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL)))return FALSE;

    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        bits,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        16,
        0,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0, 0, 0
    };

    if (!(hDC=GetDC(hWnd))) return FALSE;
    if (!(PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd))) return FALSE;
    if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC,PixelFormat,&pfd))return FALSE;
    if (!(hRC=wglCreateContext(hDC)))return FALSE;
    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC))return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetFocus(hWnd);
    ReSizeGLScene(width, height);
    if (!InitGL())return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    swprintf(buffer,L"message is: %d\n");
    OutputDebugStringW(buffer);
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
        {
            ReSizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam));
            return 0;
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            DrawGLScene();
            SwapBuffers(hDC);
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd,&rect);
            ValidateRect(hWnd,&rect);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL done=FALSE;
    fullscreen=FALSE;
    CreateGLWindow("NeHe's OpenGL Framework",640,480,16,fullscreen);
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your description of the problem actually indicates the opposite. You are getting what's known as "window damage" but not correctly dealing with it. This is the source of the "garbage", not repainting, but actually the lack of repainting.

Comment: The problem is that i don't get WM_PAINT message when this damage occur. I process WM_PAINT but windows doesn't warns me about that.

Comment: I found that when i put the window upon another window which is repainted constantly the window is got repainted also.